# How to dynamically make the selected color darker

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table display on HTML for my selected data and the table colors is can be dynamically change through my settings module. Now I want to make the table header darker color than the table row.

e.g: If I select the color `red` the table row will be `red` and the table header will be `dark red`.

How can I do that? Is this possible? or I need to set a fix condition for each color?

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: @Microsmsm I'm using AngularJS v1.6.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using transparency

```css
table {
  background-color: red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1 H</th>
    <th>2 H</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>    
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SASS [`darken`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method) function.

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/umtq90ay/2/).

```
$linkcolour: red;

table {
  background-color: $linkcolour;
}
thead{
  background-color: darken($linkcolour, 30%);
}
```